# Как получить из разных хэшей максимальное и минимальное значение?

Tags: javascript

С сервера приходят хэши(пример):

```
 {Cur_ID: 145, Cur_OfficialRate: 2.5};
 {Cur_ID: 145, Cur_OfficialRate: 2.7};
 {Cur_ID: 145, Cur_OfficialRate: 2.1};
```

Надо найти самое большое и маленькое Cur_OfficialRate из пришедшего с сервера

Answer (score 1):

Если все хэши лежат в массиве, назовем их hashArray, то сначала создаем массив только с теми данными, которые потребуются для сравнения:

```
const arrayRate = hashArray.map(hash => hash.Cur_OfficialRate);
```

После, с помощью оператора spread из es6 и методов Min и Max находим минимум и максимум:

```
const minRate = Math.Min(...arrayRate);
const maxRate = Math.Max(...arrayRate);
```

Вариант без spread оператора:

```
const minRate = Math.min.apply(null, arrayRate);
const maxRate = Math.max.apply(null, arrayRate);
```